# Simplify opening the file in the same folder as .jar

Tags: java, file-io, java-8

There's a runnable jar file and `data.txt` file next to it. `data.txt` may change dynamically. The program needs to read the content of this file. My first attempt at opening the file doesn't work:

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

I came to the following solution, but it is complex and a little bit awkward:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent() + "/data.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

It is difficult to understand what is going on here.

I tried `new File("./data.txt")` and NPE was thrown.

How to open `data.txt` file that is in the same folder as .jar file, but in more readable way?

Comment: I think the solution is in detail described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file

Comment: First off, don't write long-chain polymer statements, especially when you don't know what you're doing.  They are impossible to debug.

Comment: @HotLicks, in fact, I know what this specific statement does. But it needs time to understand for another person or even for me after some period of time. That's why I need better solution :)

Comment: So, break it into steps, each step assigned to a temporary.  Then you can easily debug it.  And, horror of horrors, consider actually adding comments for each step.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to locate the base path of a class file and you might find both being more complicated than necessary.

The first is what you have already in your question:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

the second is

```
URL url=MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class");
if(url.getProtocol().equals("jar"))
    url=((JarURLConnection)url.openConnection()).getJarFileURL();
else url=MyClass.class.getResource("/");// for file: directories
```

From the `URL` you can get a `UTF-8` `Reader` with:

```
Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(url.toURI()).resolveSibling("data.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you [set the `Class-Path` of the Jar file?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)  If you include a "." in the class path I think it will work as you initially envisioned.

In the Jar file's manifest:

> Class-Path: .

In the code:

```
InputStream ins = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt");
... // do stuff with stream
```

I haven't tested this, but I've done stuff similar to it, I believe it will work.