# How to access folders outside of a JAR

Tags: java, jar, packaging

I have a project in Eclipse which reads and writes new files- it works with Eclipse, but when I save it to a jar it no longer works. For example:

```
readConfig(newFile(Settings.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "chronos/Functions/config"));
```

Therefore, how do I load files from a outside source (assuming there is no way to do it inside a jar)?. For example, if I had my JAR in a folder with another called data- what would I type in to access the data folder?

Comment: './data' should do the job

Comment: Is there a specific location you must read/write the files from? You could always use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the user's home directory, then traverse from there

Comment: yeah, what @Marged said

Answer (score 0):

- If you just need to read you should be able to use `getResourceAsStream()` to read a file inside of the jar.
- If you want to read and write use a folder next to the jar file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file) for an answer.