# Jar accessing to external files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

I have a folder structured like this:

MyFolder:

- file1.xml
- file2.xml
- project.jar

But if in a class I use:

```
File f = new File("file1.xml");
```

I receive an error, because it doesnt find the file. Why?

Comment: The jar is looking within itself for that file and not finding it. You'll have to explicitly declare the directory, or move the XML files inside your jar file.

Comment: I cant move the xmls inside my jar, because i have to modify them and update them runtime.

Comment: How do you run your application? And what is your working folder at that time?

Comment: Declare the path then. Or reference it from a properties file. Try `./file1.xml` and `./file2.xml` for a start. Or place the XML_DIRECTORY in a properties file that you can read and amend. And refer to them from that root.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303 etc.

Comment: Hmmm. I just ran a test with a simple jar I created with a single Java class and it worked fine without any directory reference.

Comment: Maybe is because im using Ubuntu? Im going to try with OSX now.

Comment: Thank you ManoDestra, it worked fine with "./file.xml" :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a relative path in your code.

Example: `File f = new File("./file1.xml");`

Comment: Thanks man :) It works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows the code you posted will work, but not on Linux where the default parent file is your home.
But you can do in any OS by using:

```
public class MyClass {
  public void loadFile() {
    URL url = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    File jar = new File(url.toURI());
    File f = new File(jar.getParent(), "file1.xml");
    //your code
  }
}
```

PS: This needs to be inside project.jar because you are getting the location where you jar file is.