# log4j.properties outside the non executable jar file

Tags: java, log4j

I have a library (non- executable) jar file and I need to place the `log4j.properties` outside the jar.

In executable jar files, I can pass the path through `-Dlog4j.configuration`. But how can I do it in this case?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file

Comment: No.. That won't work for me. Mine is non-executable jar file and log4j.properties

Comment: How are you using this jar file?

Comment: It's a jar file with only the business logic in it. So other applications add this jar as dependency and uses the methods in it

Answer (score 0):

From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html:

> The exact default initialization algorithm is defined as follows:
>
> 1. Setting the log4j.defaultInitOverride system property to any other value then "false" will cause log4j to skip the default initialization procedure (this procedure).
> 2. Set the resource string variable to the value of the log4j.configuration system property. The preferred way to specify the default initialization file is through the log4j.configuration system property. In case the system property log4j.configuration is not defined, then set the string variable resource to its default value "log4j.properties".
> 3. Attempt to convert the resource variable to a URL.
> 4. If the resource variable cannot be converted to a URL, for example due to a MalformedURLException, then search for the resource from the classpath by calling org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.getResource(resource, Logger.class) which returns a URL. Note that the string "log4j.properties" constitutes a malformed URL.
>      See Loader.getResource(java.lang.String) for the list of searched locations.
> 5. If no URL could not be found, abort default initialization. Otherwise, configure log4j from the URL.
>      The PropertyConfigurator will be used to parse the URL to configure log4j unless the URL ends with the ".xml" extension, in which case the DOMConfigurator will be used. You can optionaly specify a custom configurator. The value of the log4j.configuratorClass system property is taken as the fully qualified class name of your custom configurator. The custom configurator you specify must implement the Configurator interface.

You can use `PropertyConfigurator.configure` to initialize log4j and specify the path to your `log4j.properties` via a system property, another config file, an environment variable, etc.

However, you may not want to have a separate logging mechanism/configuration for your JAR instead of letting it use the one(s) from the application(s) calling it.