# FileInputStream Javafx in .jar files

Tags: java, jar, fileinputstream

I am creating a Javafx application in Intelij and `FileInputStream` works perfectly. However, when I create a .jar file from the project and try to run it the code fails to run as it is unable to locate the file in the file input stream.
Here is my code:

```
ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/settingStorage.bin"));
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is always some issue accessing a file outside a jar, depending on where the file location is. You can check this SO question/answer to have an idea on accessing your file.

[Read properties file outside JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT: Look at this again, I left part out.**

```
ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream(“settingStorage.bin")));
```

This usually works for me. When I run this, it operates fine, in AND out of the development area. Don’t include /src, as when you call getResourceAsStream off a class, it already checks inside the jar.

Cheers!

Comment: which class should SomeClass be the class that this line of code is in?

Comment: @joshLor yeah, that would probably be optimal, but it could be any class inside your src folder. Safer to do it the line of code it’s in though.

Comment: This does not work it says can not resolve contractors FileInputStream (java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Oh wait I forgot, I’m going to edit the code, use that.

Comment: .toURI is not a method for Input streams but files I think

Comment: That’s probably what I’m missing.

Comment: The only problem is that this is happening in the start method so when I use that I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @joshLor please explain what you mean by that

Comment: I do not know why but if the file is found SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream(“settingStorage.bin") returns null.